# select * from (select first_name, last_name from employees)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I do understand the meaning of this statement but I don't understand why do we need this?
This is equivalent to

```
select first_Name, last_name from employees
```

I can see this type of statements in many examples. Can you please explain when we need this? In practical do we use this type of statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Can you please explain when we need this?*

These are called **Derived Tables**.

> A "derived table" is essentially a statement-local temporary table
>   created by means of a subquery in the FROM clause of a SQL SELECT
>   statement. It exists only in memory and behaves like a standard view
>   or table.

**In SQL, subqueries can only see values from parent queries one level deep.**

> *In practical do we use this type of statements?*

The most common use of it is the **classic row-limiting query using ROWNUM**.

**Row-Limiting query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   emp 
        ORDER  BY sal DESC) 
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 5;
```

**Pagination query:**

```
SELECT eno 
FROM  (SELECT e.empno  eno, 
              e.ROWNUM rn 
       FROM   (SELECT empno 
               FROM   emp 
               ORDER  BY sal DESC) e) 
WHERE  rn <= 5;
```

Comment: Nitpicking: `from (select ... )` is called a "derived table", not a sub-select. Btw: the visibility rule is is defined by the SQL standard, it's not Oracle specific.

Comment: Thanks Lalit. Just curious to know if you could suggest good books for Oracle Flashback technology and SQL Tuning.

Comment: @SanjayChauhan For SQL Tuning book, go to my profile, and follow the link in the technical book reviews.

Comment: @SanjayChauhan I have reviewed this book http://www.amazon.com/dp/1501022695/?tag=stackoverfl08-20 by Kevin Meade. I find it really good.

Comment: Thanks @Lalit Kumar B. After covering my basics, I will go with this book.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of statement is useless, you're right, but there are many occasions when you need a subselect because you can't do everything in one statement. Of the top of my head I'd be thinking about for instance, combining aggregate functions, get the min, max and avg of a sum

```
select min(t.summed), max(t.summed), avg(t.summed) 
from (select type, sum(value) as summed from table1 group by type) t
```

this is just from the top of my head, but I did encounter many occasions where subselects in the from clause were necessary. Once the statements are complex enough you'll see it.